# Error Using Crispy Form on my Django projects

Tags: python, django

I got an Error Using Crispy Form on my Django projects.
I added 'crispy-forms' in the INSTALLED_APPS under setting
here is the code

> INSTALLED_APPS = [
>
> ```
> 'django.contrib.admin',
> 'django.contrib.auth',
> 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
> 'django.contrib.sessions',
> 'django.contrib.messages',
> 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
> 'employee_register',
> 'crispy_forms',
> ```
>
> ]

Also added to setting

> `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'`

and on my html as

```
{% extends 'employee_register/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="" autocomplete="off" class="uniForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }}

</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Here is the error

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

What could be the problem please?
Thank You.

Comment: Please check whether you have ran makemigrations and migrate commands.

Comment: Thank  you. it working now. i did pip install django-crispy-form

Comment: Thank  you. it working now. i did pip install django-crispy-form